# How to verify StructureMap is disposing of objects properly

Tags: nhibernate, structuremap

I'm currently using StructureMap to inject instances of NHibernate ISessions using the following code:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.ForRequestedType<ISession>()
        .CacheBy(InstanceScope.PerRequest)
        .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(y => NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession());    
});
```

I'm assuming that the CacheBy(InstanceScope.PerRequest) will properly dispose of the ISession it creates, but I'd like to make sure. What's the easiest way to test this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so according to the [StructureMap documentation](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/Glossary.htm#section4):

> Also note that StructureMap provides
>   no functionality for cleaning up
>   resources of the objects held by the
>   container
>   (Container.EjectAllInstances() will
>   clear out singleton objects).  To
>   date, I have not found a need for this
>   behavior or functionality.  I
>   generally assume that a combination of
>   basic garbage collection and proper
>   class design is sufficient.

I know it's best practice to call ISession.Dispose() when using NHibernate, so either I need to manually clean it up myself or simply rely on garbage collection to do it for me.

Comment: Yes, you need to manually clean it up (don't rely on GC). Check out http://trason.net/journal/2009/10/7/bootstrapping-nhibernate-with-structuremap.html